# What libraries do game engines use behind the scene?

Tags: game-engine

I know that each graphic driver like Nvidia, AMD, Intel etc. supports a select list of libraries as their interface such as OpenGL, directx or vulkan.

Which one of these libraries are used by popular game engines like Unity and Unreal Engine?

Comment: The best way to get answers to these sorts of questions is to look through the documentation for these engines.  UE4: https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/ Unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/index.html

The short answer is that most big game engines support multiple, and abstract their code in such a way that you can essentially flick a switch to use another.

Answer (score -1):

I think they would most likely be done with OpenGL.  But it really matters. There isn't just a single library all game engines use but I'm sure you already know that